# how do you manager your assumed role IAM policies to access secrets in AWS secret manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am starting migrating our secrets from AWS parameter store to AWS secret manager, currently I am facing a problem that I don't how to solve, could anyone provide any insight?

We have a AWS account (let's call it identity account), which we manage all IAM users and groups. And we have another AWS account which hosts our infra (let's call this infra account). We'd like to manage all users in the identity account and let user assumes to `poweruser` role in the infra account so we can manage all users at one place.

In the infra account, we have RDS running and we want to create DB users for our developers so they can login to database for debugging purpose, but we also want to audit what they have done in case someone did something bad to our database, so we need to create one DB user per developer. All of those DB credentials are saved into AWS secret with a naming convention like 

`/dev/rds/mysql/users/foo
/dev/rds/mysql/users/bar`

So here is the question: *how can I manage user's IAM policy to restrict the permission of user so they can ONLY access their own secret?* From [this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) that we *CANNOT* get `aws:username` when user is using assumed role to access AWS, thus the following policy would never work

```
actions   = [
  "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
  "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage"
]
resources = [
  "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678912:secret:/dev/rds/mysql/users/${aws:username}"
]
```

The only IAM variable that I can use for assumed role is `aws:userid` but it would be something like this (assume user `foo`'s username in identity account is `foo@emaildomain.com`)

```
"AROAJGHLP6KERYI375PJY:foo@emaildomain.com"
```

It also looks like that the `role-id` (`AROAJGHLP6KERYI375PJY` in this example) is random, with prefix `AROA`, which means I *CANNOT* use following policy either (and plus, having `AROAJGHLP6KERYI375PJY:foo@emaildomain.com` as a secret name in secret manager is pretty ugly)

```
actions   = [
  "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
  "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage"
]
resources = [
  "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678912:secret:/dev/rds/mysql/users/${aws:userid}"
]
```

Currently my policy ended up with this

```
actions   = [
  "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
  "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage"
]
resources = [
  "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678912:secret:/dev/rds/mysql/users/*"
]
```

which means as long as user assumed to infra account, they have access to other developers DB credentials as well.

I've looked into CloudWatch metric to see if I can setup a filter to filter out the API call that user `foo` is calling `GetSecretValue` API to get user `bar`'s credential, but CloudWatch filter doesn't support user REGEX to extract certain value from JSON. Here's the example of the `GetSecretValue` event from CloudTrail log:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAJGHLP6KERYI375PJY:foo@emaildomain.com",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::12345678912:assumed-role/poweruser/foo@emaildomain.com",
        "accountId": "12345678912",
        "accessKeyId": "ASIATA5XIF7AFC2CQ7NO",
        "sessionContext": {
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
                "creationDate": "2018-07-11T21:31:20Z"
            },
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAJGHLP6KERYI375PJY",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345678912:role/poweruser",
                "accountId": "12345678912",
                "userName": "poweruser"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2018-07-11T21:32:56Z",
    "eventSource": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "GetSecretValue",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "1.2.3.4",
    "userAgent": "aws-internal/3",
    "requestParameters": {
        "secretId": "/dev/rds/mysql/users/foo"
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "f98ad2c2-8551-11e8-8a3f-751b0a8a6ca5",
    "eventID": "73b8de89-bc8c-41a3-a172-58dd8d79a026",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "12345678912"
}
```

If I can extract `foo@emaildomain.com` from `{ $.userIdentity.principalId }` and extract `foo` from to  `{ $.requestParameters}` then I can try some magic to compare `foo@emaildomain.com == foo` to trigger alert if user is trying to get other people's credential, but, I can't...

So, in this case, how could I manage my policy to lock users' permission?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

From your first example, for each user, can you try to hardcode the secret in their user iam policy?

So for user foo, the user policy would look something like

```
 ...
    actions   = [
  "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
  "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
  "secretsmanager:UpdateSecretVersionStage"
]
resources = [
  "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345678912:secret:/dev/rds/mysql/users/foo"
]
 ...
```

You would have the same structure for bar, ...

If you have many users, this solution wouldn't scale

Comment: Dude ur a smart guy

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using a common assumed role for all the users. An alternative to this would be to create a resource policy on each secret that granted access permissions to the owning user in the identity account. This would let the users access the secret directly without calling assumerole. This would not prevent them from still assuming the infra account poweruser role and accessing the secret, so you would either have to drop Secrets Manager privileges from the role, or explicitly deny the infra power user in the resource policy you add to the secret.

Setting up cross account access like this also means you can not use the default KMS encryption key. You will need to setup a custom KMS key that grants the [correct access permission](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-access-secrets-across-aws-accounts-by-attaching-resource-based-policies/) to the identity account and re-encrypt the secrets with that new key.

Since resource policies and custom KMS keys can not be setup in the Secrets Manager Console, this all requires using the CLI or one of the SDKs.